# Event emit error

Tags: stenciljs

so I have this code -

```
@Component({
  tag: "app-home",
  styleUrl: "app-home.css"
})
export class AppHome {
  @Event()
  myEvent: EventEmitter;

  callEv() {
    this.myEvent.emit("hello");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="app-home">
        <button onClick={this.callEv}>Hello</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When the button is clicked, I get this error in the console -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.callEv
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `callEv` method, you use the `this` keyword to call the event emitter service. But inside the template, the context is different and therefore `this` does not contain the event emitter service, which causes your error.

What you need to do is to bind the current context to the method. Add this to your class:

```
constructor() {
    this.callEv = this.callEv.bind(this);
}
```